# Ignore properties with custom attribute set, using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

I have written a generic method that generates a collection of generic types from a Datatable. I have looked for different implementations, but most of them were performing very poorly performance wise when dealing with lots of properties and a lot of records. This one is performing quite well so far.

I tried to improve the method by adding a custom attribute ( DataField ) on top of the properties, this way I could just include it on the properties and I can skip matching it up with the columns, or specify a custom name for the property that will match the datatable's column name.

I looked at the code and it looks like a huge mess now I'm really not proud of it and I want to have a nicer implementation. Can anyone give me some tips? Would appreciate it a lot.

Tried to include comments not sure how much it helped. Thank you, here is the code:

```
private static void SetItemFromRow<T>(T item, DataRow row) where T : new()
    {
        // Get all properties with attributes.
        PropertyInfo[] propWithAttributes = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined
          (x, typeof(DataField))).ToArray();

        foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            // Find property that matches the column name.
            PropertyInfo p = item.GetType().GetProperty(col.ColumnName);
            bool ignoreProperty = false;

            if (p != null)
            {
                // If no attribute exists set the property value. Break out from the loop to go to the next column (Property).
                if (!propWithAttributes.Contains(p))
                {
                    if (row[col] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        p.SetValue(item, row[col], null);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                // If the property has a custom attribute then check if its ignore property is true. If so we break out from the loop and go to the next column (Property). 
                var attrs = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataField), false).ToArray() as DataField[]; ;

                if (attrs != null)
                    foreach (var attr in attrs)
                    {
                        if (attr.Ignore)
                            ignoreProperty = true;
                    }

                if (ignoreProperty) continue;
            }

            SetPropertyWithCustomName(item, propWithAttributes, row, col);    
        }
    }
```

Now we have all properties set on the object that had a matching column name, also we skipped all the properties that we wanted to ignore. Final step is to set the properties that have a DataField attribute with the Name defined.

```
            private static void SetPropertyWithCustomName<T>(T item, PropertyInfo[] propWithAttributes,  DataRow row,  DataColumn col)
        where T : new()
    {

        foreach (var prop in propWithAttributes)
        {
            // Get the attributes for the property.
            var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataField), false).ToArray() as DataField[];
            bool match = false;

            if (attrs != null)
            {
                foreach (var attr in attrs)
                {
                    // Check if the column name matches the custom name on the property.
                    if (col.ColumnName == attr.Name)
                    {
                        var p = item.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                        if (row[col] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            p.SetValue(item, row[col], null);
                            match = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if (match) break;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Define *nicier*? Easier to read? Faster? More memory efficient? In any case code review is done [there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Well More readable would do for now.

Comment: Thank I will give it a try "there" then.

Comment: You should at least cache all your calls to GetProperty. You make a lot of identical calls to GetProperty for each data row. Also it's a common convention to name attributes with Attribute suffix (DataFieldAttribute).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bit more readable version of your code (if I understand the intent correctly):

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, DataFieldProperty[]> _propsCache = new Dictionary<Type, DataFieldProperty[]>();
private static DataFieldProperty[] GetProperties(Type type) {
    lock (_propsCache) {
        if (!_propsCache.ContainsKey(type)) {
            var result = new List<DataFieldProperty>();
            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)) {
                var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DataField>();
                result.Add(new DataFieldProperty {
                    Name = attr?.Name ?? prop.Name,
                    Ignore = attr?.Ignore ?? false,
                    Property = prop
                });
           }
           _propsCache.Add(type, result.ToArray());
        }
        return _propsCache[type];
    }
}

private class DataFieldProperty {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }
    public bool Ignore { get; set; }
}

private static void SetItemFromRow<T>(T item, DataRow row) where T : new() {
    // Get all properties with attributes.
    var props = GetProperties(item.GetType());
    foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns) {
        // Find property that matches the column name.
        var p = props.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == col.ColumnName && !c.Ignore);
        if (p != null) {
            if (row[col] != DBNull.Value) {
                p.Property.SetValue(item, row[col], null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't actually run it (but verified it compiles).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I will test it in a second and give feedback.

Comment: Hi, its certainly a lot less code and less nested for each. I tested it and works perfectly, I didn't have vs2015 and C# 6 so had to do small adjustments but  yeah it works! Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. It also caches GetProperty calls, so should be a bit faster on large sets.

Comment: My only question is, why use lock there?

Comment: Because you can use that for different row sets, from different threads. As a general rule, access to all static fields should be thread safe. You can remove lock if you are sure SetItemFromRow is never called by different threads at the same time, but that is very hard to enforce.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thanks I really like this implementation!